# Mongoose Query: Find an element inside an array

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Mongoose/Mongo noob here:

**My Data**

Here is my simplified data, each user has his own document

```
{ "__v" : 1,
  "_id" : ObjectId( "53440e94c02b3cae81eb0065" ),
  "email" : "test@test.com",
  "firstName" : "testFirstName",
  "inventories" : [ 
    { "_id" : "active",
      "tags" : [ 
        "inventory", 
        "active", 
        "vehicles" ],
      "title" : "activeInventory",
      "vehicles" : [ 
        { "_id" : ObjectId( "53440e94c02b3cae81eb0069" ),
          "tags" : [ 
            "vehicle" ],
          "details" : [ 
            { "_id" : ObjectId( "53440e94c02b3cae81eb0066" ),
              "year" : 2007,
              "transmission" : "Manual",
              "price" : 1000,
              "model" : "Firecar",
              "mileageReading" : 50000,
              "make" : "Bentley",
              "interiorColor" : "blue",
              "history" : "CarProof",
              "exteriorColor" : "blue",
              "driveTrain" : "SWD",
              "description" : "test vehicle",
              "cylinders" : 4,
              "mileageType" : "kms" } ] } ] }, 
    { "title" : "soldInventory",
      "_id" : "sold",
      "vehicles" : [],
      "tags" : [ 
        "inventory", 
        "sold", 
        "vehicles" ] }, 
    { "title" : "deletedInventory",
      "_id" : "deleted",
      "vehicles" : [],
      "tags" : [ 
        "inventory", 
        "sold", 
        "vehicles" ] } ] }
```

As you can see, each user has an `inventories` property that is an array that contains 3 inventories (activeInventory, soldInventory and deletedInventory)

**My Query**

Given an user's email a a vehicle ID, i would like my query to go through find the user's `activeInventory` and return just the vehicle that matches the ID. Here is what I have so far:

```
user = api.mongodb.userModel;
ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;
return user
    .findOne({email : params.username})
    .select('inventories')
    .find({'title': 'activeInventory'})
    //also tried
    //.where('title')
    //.equals('activeInventory')
    .exec(function(err, result){
        console.log(err);
        console.log(result);
    });
```

With this, result comes out as an empty array. I've also tried `.find('inventories.title': 'activeInventory')` which strangely returns the entire inventories array. If possible, I'd like to keep the chaining query format as I find it much more readable.

**My Ideal Query**

```
return user
    .findOne({email : params.username})
    .select('inventories')
    .where('title')
    .equals('activeInventory')
    .select('vehicles')
    .id(vehicleID)
    .exec(cb)
```

Obviously it does not work but it can give you an idea what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using the [`$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) positional operator, you can get the results.  However, if you have multiple elements in the `vehicles` array all of them will be returned in the result, as you can only use one positional operator in the projection and you are working with 2 arrays (one inside another).

I would suggest you take a look at the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/aggregation-introduction/), as you'll get a lot more flexibility.  Here's an example query for your question that runs in the shell.  I'm not familiar with mongoose, but I guess this will still help you and you'd be able to translate it:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    // Get only the documents where "email" equals "test@test.com" -- REPLACE with params.username
    {"$match" : {email : "test@test.com"}}, 
    // Unwind the "inventories" array
    {"$unwind" : "$inventories"}, 
    // Get only elements where "inventories.title" equals "activeInventory"
    {"$match" : {"inventories.title":"activeInventory"}}, 
    // Unwind the "vehicles" array
    {"$unwind" : "$inventories.vehicles"}, 
    // Filter by vehicle ID -- REPLACE with vehicleID 
    {"$match" : {"inventories.vehicles._id":ObjectId("53440e94c02b3cae81eb0069")}}, 
    // Tidy up the output
    {"$project" : {_id:0, vehicle:"$inventories.vehicles"}}
])
```

This is the output you'll get:

```js
{
        "result" : [
                {
                        "vehicle" : {
                                "_id" : ObjectId("53440e94c02b3cae81eb0069"),
                                "tags" : [
                                        "vehicle"
                                ],
                                "details" : [
                                        {
                                                "_id" : ObjectId("53440e94c02b3cae81eb0066"),
                                                "year" : 2007,
                                                "transmission" : "Manual",
                                                "price" : 1000,
                                                "model" : "Firecar",
                                                "mileageReading" : 50000,
                                                "make" : "Bentley",
                                                "interiorColor" : "blue",
                                                "history" : "CarProof",
                                                "exteriorColor" : "blue",
                                                "driveTrain" : "SWD",
                                                "description" : "test vehicle",
                                                "cylinders" : 4,
                                                "mileageType" : "kms"
                                        }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Comment: I love the approach, your approach is nice

Answer (score 3):

getting the chaining query format ... i dont know how to parse it but, what you are searching for is projection, you should take a look to http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/

it would probably look like this :

```
user.findOne({email: params.username}, {'inventories.title': {$elemMatch: "activeInventory", 'invertories.vehicle.id': $elemMatch: params.vehicleId}, function(err, result) {
    console.log(err);
    console.log(result);
})
```